# Css specificity :last-child

Tags: css, css-specificity, css-selectors

I would like to use the following to target the last link (a) of the last ul inside my div. So this is what came to mind:

```
#menu ul:last-child li a {
       /*.....*/
}
```

I cant manually add a class to that element, and even if i wanted to do it dynamically i would still have to target the element the above way.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: It will nice if you'll provide HTML sample

Comment: sorry I should have attched one but i just needed ideas ... Anyway, for some inexplicable reason none of my browsers seem to respond to :last-child or :first-child. I just made it work in jQuery :

$('#menu ul li a:last').css({});

Answer (score 9):

If you want the *last link* in the *last ul* (assuming the link is inside a `li`-element), this is what you want:

```
#menu ul:last-child li:last-child a {
       /*.....*/
}
```

- `#menu` returns the menu element.
- `ul:last-child` returns the last `ul` within `#menu`
- `li:last-child` returns the last `li` within that `ul`

Haven't tried it, but i guess this would work.

Comment: It works.....but just one doubt,regarding your explanation.....Isn't it this way... #menu ul selects all uls within #menu; :last-child li selects the last li within all menu uls; and :last-child a selects the last link within the last li?I just used it for a horizontal navigation, where the last li doesn't have a submenu ul, and it selects that particular li.......

Answer (score 4):

I'm only guessing what your HTML is, but:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css" >
    div ul:last-child li:last-child a:last-child {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul><li>First list</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Second list</li></ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">First Link</a>
            <a href="#">Last Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in safari (4.0.3) and firefox(3.5.4) and all works fine, I don't know in IE8!

Consider that this is a new pseudo-class (selector) defined in the CSS3 standard that is not completely supported from all browsers and is unsupported by the oldest browsers!

As general rule, for performance reasons, I suggest you to avoid CSS directives with more than 2 level (maximum 3 if you really need it)!

However, I think that if you don't want to apply the style directly to a tagged element, you have to find a javascript solution!

Answer (score 0):

CSS `last-child` **does not work in IE, including IE8**.

It should work in all other current browsers, but if you're planning to use it on a site which needs to support IE, you'll need to work out an alternative way to do it.

This page has a full list of CSS selectors, and which browsers support them:
http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: :last-child works in IE 9 and up. :first-child works since IE7.

Comment: @Dima you are correct. Bear in mind that IE9 had not been released when this answer was posted.

Comment: of course, the answer was posted more than 7 years ago. This is just an update.